# ics file, not able to download when anonymous?

Tags: 2010, calendar

I used the following method to create a ics file from a custom list:

```
http://<site-url>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=<LISTGUID>&CacheControl=1&ID=<ITEMID>&Using=event.ics
```

Although I am unable to download the ics file anonymously? What could be the issue? is this possible?

Comment: is this done through codebehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order for anonymous users to access the ics file, i belive that they dont have access to the list?

where are you generating the download function? if its through code then you can use impersonation!

If its from the list that is the issue than set it to all users who can have access, if you dont want all users to have access than you need to use impersonation to access the ics file without logging in!

Comment: I need to break the permission and give the specific list which contains the ics file access to all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Deactivate the feature "**ViewFormPagesLockDown**":

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -url http://SERVERNAME/sites/SITENAME -filename ViewFormPagesLockDown\feature.xml
```

For more info check my blog post:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/choroshin/archive/2012/11/06/sharepoint-getting-authentication-login-prompt-when-trying-to-open-office-document-with-unique-permissions.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I already have that part down. My issue is that I am only able to download the item when I am signed in. I would like users to be able to download the file, without having to sign in.

Comment: Hi Diana, I updated my answer, have you tried deactivatig the feature “ViewFormPagesLockDown”?

Comment: Hi Alex, I want anonymous users to be able to download the item. I do not  want them to sign in...which is what will happen if I deactivate the "viewformpageslockdown".

Comment: Basically I had the same problem, I got authentication login prompt and after deactivating the feature “ViewFormPagesLockDown” i got it to work without the login prompt